# Center a Modal div element with css

Tags: css, modal-dialog, center

I have a div, called modal, that is in the back and I have a modal-c element and I can't figure out why is the modal-c element in the top left not centered.

```css
.modal {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.modal-c {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 3%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal" id="myModal<?php echo $id;?>" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-c">
    <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/add-invoice.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><button class="add-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-file-invoice"></i></button></a>
    <br><br><br>
    <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/bill.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><button class="add-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-print"></i></button></a>
    <br><br><br>
    <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/images.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><button class="add-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-camera"></i></button></a>
    <br><br><br>
    <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/show-images.php?workbook_id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><button class="add-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-image"></i></button></a>
    <br><br>
    <button type="button" class="danger-btn" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is how It looks like:
[image: modal-c in top left]

I want the Modal to be centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the flex properties on a parent, that has a width and height of 100% of the viewport. You cannot call these properties as they will conflict your code;

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
```

```css
div {
  width: 100vw; 
  height: 100vh; 
  background: #C7FFF0;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div.modal {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #007AFF;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class=modal></div>
</div>
```